# A fear of or the fear of

Tags: articles

"I have a fear of flying" vs "I have the fear of flying."
Do they both mean exactly the same thing? Or have slightly different meanings? Or is it just that the "fear" has been mentioned before, so use "the".

Comment: The fear would only have been mentioned before in the context of somebody saying *I have* ***the same*** *fear of flying* in response to a previous statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

“A fear” is correct because you’re not referring to a specific instance of fear.